# how to delete object array from node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am creating a simple todolist using react js and node js without database (to store data in objact array) I need to delete elements one by one by clicking. For each element I have `Delete button`. now todo list delete from front end(react), how to delete it from node any one please help me

todo.js

```
 

function Remove(id) {
  const updateTodos=[...tasks].filter((obj)=>obj.id!==id)
  setTasks(updateTodos)
  
 } 

 if(isLogged){
  
  return (
  
      <div >
        <h1>ToDo List</h1>
        <form onSubmit={HandleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" placeholder=" Add item..." name="list" value={toDos} onChange={(e)=>setToDos(e.target.value)}/>
        <button id="btn" type="submit">Add</button>
       
        
        </form>
        <ul>
          {tasks.map(obj=><li key={obj.id}>{obj.toDo}<button type='delete' onClick={(e)=>Remove(obj.id)} >Delete</button>
          <input type="checkbox" id="" name=""onChange={(e)=>{
            console.log(e.target.checked)
            console.log(obj)
            setTasks(tasks.filter(obj2=>{
              if(obj2.id===obj.id){
                obj2.status=e.target.checked
              }
              return obj2
            }))
          }} value={obj.status}  /> </li>)}
        </ul>

        <h4>Completed tasks</h4>
        {tasks.map((obj)=>{
          if(obj.status){
            return(<h5>{obj.toDos}</h5>)
          }
          return null
        })}

      </div>


  );
  }


}

export default Todo;
```

node- index.js

```
const lists =[
    {id: new Date(),toDo:"learn react"}
]
app.post('/Todo',function(req, res){

            lists.push({"id":new Date(),"toDo":req.body.list,"status":false})
    console.log(lists)
    res.status(200).json(lists[lists.length-1])
 })

 app.get('/Todo', (request, response) => response.status(200).json(lists));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
req.body.list.pop()
res.status(200).json({"id":new Date(),"toDo":req.body.list,"status":false})
```

This will remove the last element in the list

Comment: i want delete elements by that button

Comment: use also a `form` tag with action pointing to that endpoint in the backend and your button is gonna be of type `submit`